# Draw some ASCII stars

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Write a program or function that draws an ASCII star, given the size of the arms as input.

Here's a star of size `1`

```
_/\_
\  /
|/\|
```

Here's a star of size `2`

```
   /\
__/  \__
\      /
 \    /
 | /\ |
 |/  \|
```

Here's a star of size `3`

```
     /\
    /  \
___/    \___
\          /
 \        /
  \      /
  |  /\  |
  | /  \ |
  |/    \|
```

And so on.

#### Input

A single positive integer [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963), `n > 0`.

#### Output

An ASCII-art representation of a star, following the above rules. Leading/trailing newlines or other whitespace are optional, provided that the points line up appropriately.

#### Rules

- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Is it just my screen, or do the stars look abnormally tall and thin?

Comment: Stupid ASCII and its lack of shallow slants...

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The font used by SE isn't square - there's significant whitespace between lines, which increases the distortion.

Answer (score 12):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>20</s> 17 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Neil.*

```
Ｎν↙ν↑↑ν↖ν ×_ν↗ν‖Ｍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SCNPk4sroCgzr0TDyiW/PM8nNa1ERwEo6JtflqphFVqAkA4tAEsguHC1EBElBSW4rJaGUrwSSE4ToTwoMz0Dop4rKDUtJzW5xDezqCi/SEPz/3/j/7pl/3WLcwA) Link is to verbose version.

I'm pretty happy with this golf so...

### Explanation

```
Ｎν                 take a number as input and store in ν
  ↙ν               print / ν times downwards to the left
    ↑              move up once
     ↑ν            print | ν times upwards
       ↖ν          print \ ν times upwards to the left
                   print a space
          ×_ν      print _ ν times
             ↗ν    print / ν times upwards to the right
               ‖Ｍ  reflect horizontally
```

```
     /\                           
    /  \    "No, this is Patrick!"
___/    \___                      
\   ☉ ☉    /                      
 \       /                       
  \      /                        
  |  /\  |                        
  | /  \ |                        
  |/    \|
```

Comment: Drawing it bottom to top saves 2 bytes.

Comment: [For some reason, I have to increment the argument to `Polygon`...](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SCNPk4sroCgzr0TDyiW/PM8nNa1ERwEo6JtflqphFVqAkA4tAEsguGhqgzLTM0pA8vk5len5eVABoAIdBaV4JWSNMAmgWFBqWk5qcolvZlFRfpGG5v//hv91y/7rFucAAA "Charcoal – Try It Online") Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's because `Polygon` leaves the cursor on the last character, but I wasn't using `Polygon`... in fact I wasn't using the best code either, I'm down to 17 now.

Comment: I dunno if if I got 17 the same way you did but... Thanks!

Comment: Near enough. I actually had `Move(:Right); for (n) Print("_");`.

Answer (score 5):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>27</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
╔*¹.╚№┼№.╝+ø┐.∙.1ž.╚┼+╬³
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyNTU0KiVCOS4ldTI1NUEldTIxMTYldTI1M0MldTIxMTYuJXUyNTVEKyVGOCV1MjUxMC4ldTIyMTkuMSV1MDE3RS4ldTI1NUEldTI1M0MrJXUyNTZDJUIz,inputs=Mw__)

Explanation:

```
╔*                        push a string with input amount of underscores
  ¹                       wrap that in an array
   .╚                     push a "/" diagonal of the size of the input (the top lines)
     №                    reverse vertically
      ┼                   add horizontally the underscores behind the array
       №                  reverse vertically back
        .╝+               below that add a "\" diagonal (middle lines)
           ø              push an empty string as the base of the vertical bars
            ┐.∙           get an array of "|" with the length of the input
               .1ž        at [input; 1] in the empty string insert that
                  .╚┼     horizontally append a "/" diagonal
                     +    add that below everything else
                      ╬³  palindromize horizontally
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>166 160 157 155</s>  152 bytes

The `exec` approach is exactly the same byte count.

```python
i=input();t,z=" \\";y=t*2
for k in range(i*3):s=k%i;o=i+~s;p=i+o;g="_ "[i>k+1]*p;print[g+"/"+y*k+z+g,t*s+z+y*p+"/",~-i*t+"|"+o*t+"/"+y*s+z+o*t+"|"][k/i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBCsIwEIXhvacIA0I7UylW3BjiRdoiLjQOgSQ04yJFevXY6uqD/72Y5RV8Vwob9vEtVa2lmQ2oYQCdjWC3e4ZJOcVeTXdvHxXjqb4k4/asg2Fako4rQVsDNwU9Xx0dR4w6TuyltwQtUEZHM9lGMK1mjFttlgOjEHyAwubvt@3hX8fetTyWcv4C)

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech).*

Comment: You could save some bytes by replacing `t=" ";y,z=t*2,"\\"` with `t,z=" \\";y=t+t`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>385</s> <s>376</s> <s>344</s> <s>304</s> <s>285</s> <s>280</s> <s>268</s> <s>264</s> <s>252</s> 250 <s>+ 19</s> bytes

```
n->{int s=2*n,w=2*s,e=n-1,i=0,o,l[][]=new int[n*3][w];for(;i<n;l[i][s+~i]=l[n+i][w+~i]=l[o][s+~i]=47,l[i][o]=l[o][o]=l[n+i][i]=92,l[e][i]=l[e][w-++i]=95,l[o][e]=l[o][s+n]=124)o=s+i;for(int[]b:l)System.out.println(new String(b,0,w).replace("�"," "));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZAxb8MgEIW72r8CecIxRkmaqGodsnTq0CkjYiAOiUjJYQGOVUXpX3ex62YB3ruP43hneZWlbRScD1990@6NrlFtpPfoU2pAtzTxQYZoniNI26ANPbZQB22Bvlvw7UW5zQcEdVJuixqnIeyCdIj1UG5vUSHPljMgXVw9UQzKBdFsTiwxXHDBQHUoUhxmz4J3ojpahyu9gcpwLbgvfrRghkMRRTcJ@@@vXshI2cm1DzQWX5exqMbjuHdlUQz2moysenQCwRbLVW6ZL/T4/DCO2L@ZfPftg7pQ2wY6fswAHsbdhShOeE/mpMupU42RtcLZU0YylOV5de@TKk2TKcwpvqvVB3SJkeK/61wg6U4@HxJOHrFRWdeqCXgKlDbSeRUFHlg@F7F7mtzTe9@vfwE)

Comment: You can shorten it by 10 bytes using bitwise tricks and moving all your integer declarations outside your loops ([270 bytes](https://tio.run/##PVC7TsMwFGXOV1hZkjSpKSAm112YGJg6GguZ1C0OznVkO42iUn49OA/q4VrnoaOjU4mzWJtGQnX4HlTdGOtRFTjceqXxsYXSKwN4RaKoaT@1KlGphXPoTShAlyiKUHjOCx@UFwOuraXdvoKXJ2l3qEIUDbDeXRR45OjjCoouXFdICuuHQtFN0dMNKb@EZZxxTUF2aEKweuKs4@RobErUFojK82yKMdTlimimOHP5r@JUM8gD6BZg/vnkPpltZqHNzTuq7@@jLCcw/XNA8jHSwS1vYRDYn4Rcpy79NlQj@955WWPTetzY0EpDOlbf@wBOqWZ9nvMMW9loUco0vouLGMVZlpHrQObNljWX6c5GHVAdNk3nCMZFdqmwKEvZ@HTZEzfCOhlAKtiGj2HXYXj@Aw))

Comment: And you can save yet another 2 bytes by moving the `int o=` outside the loop too ([268 bytes](https://tio.run/##PVA9b8MgFOzsX4G82I4dmrbqRJylU4dOGQmqiENSXPywAMey3PSvu/ijQYKnu3c6HVfyK1/rWkB5@h5kVWvjUOk53Dip8LmBwkkNeEWCoG6OShaoUNxa9MEloD4IAuSPddz5zZsG21TCbN/BiYswO1SiHA2w3vUSHLL58wqy1r82EzmsnzKZb7LOX02KL24oo0zlIFo0IVi9MNoyctYmJnILRKZp0uvcppIoKhm16a9kuaKQetAuQP/z0WM0y/RC67t23B4O41pMYJqzQfQ50l4t7mbg2Z@I3KYc3dbHIvvOOlFh3ThcG/81BfEYe@88uMSKdmnKEmxErXgh4vAhzEIUJklCbgOZG1u6XIq7anlClW80ni0o40lfYl4Uonbx0iauubHCg5jTDRvNbsPw@gc))

Comment: You can save 4 more bytes by getting rid of the for-loop brackets and using `++` directly on the last occurrence of `i`, like this: [**264 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y9mz6txr).

Comment: [252 bytes](https://tio.run/##PVA9b8MgEO3sX4E82bGNkjRR1RKydOrQKSNiwA6JcPGBDI4VWelfd4njhgF4H3ccrxYXURgroT7@jKqxpvWoDhzuvNL41EHllQG8IFFku1KrClVaOIe@hQI0RFGEwnJe@KB8GnBdI9vdF3h5lu0e1YiiEYr9oMAjR9cLyPuwu1xSKFa5osvckPLqJeOMawqyRxOCxStnPScn0yZE7YBopjhz2a/iVDPIAuhnYP75zVs@uczMmqc1iO/rIMrpOp19kWV3eptPXvnsBJyu1pvUUJep6fnHdOWHTg9X52WDTeexbcOHNCT3gQ8@gHNSpriVVotKJvFLnMcoTlNyG8kjoTm7OaiLUUfUhASTRzHjIh1qLKpKWp/M6WErWicDSARb8nuz2zhu/wA "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Nevay Very clever, thank you

Comment: RIP my solution. You can lose two more bytes by using an `int[][]` for the character data: [TIO](https://tio.run/##PZAxb8MgEIW72r8CecIxRkmaqGodsnTq0CkjYiAOiUjJYQGOVUXpX3ex62YB3ruP43hneZWlbRScD1990@6NrlFtpPfoU2pAtzTxQYZoniNI26ANPbZQB22Bvlvw7UW5zQcEdVJuixqnIeyCdIj1UG5vUSHPljMgXVw9UQzKBdFsTiwxXHDBQHUoUhxmz4J3ojpahyu9gcpwLbgvfrRghkMRRTcJ@@@vXshI2cm1DzQWX5exqMbjuHdlUQz2moysenQCwRbLVW6ZL/T4/DCO2L@ZfPftg7pQ2wY6fswAHsbdhShOeE/mpMupU42RtcLZU0YylOV5de@TKk2TKcwpvqvVB3SJkeK/61wg6U4@HxJOHrFRWdeqCXgKlDbSeRUFHlg@F7F7mtzTe9@vfwE).

Comment: @Jakob I'm not too sure how mine works anymore... What does that String constructor do?

Comment: Don't be afraid to check [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html). The constructor takes Unicode code points instead of bytes (which happen to have identical data here because only ASCII is used). The `int` parameters indicate that the string should be built from the entire array.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 189 bytes

```
n(
  s_±x_±y_:=s->Array[If[x==y,s," "]&,{n,n}];
  StringRiffle[Characters@{"_/\\_","\\  /","|/\\:"}/.
    {"_"±#±n,"|"±#2±n,":"±#2±1,"\\"±#±#2,"/"±(n-#+1)±#2," "±0±1}
    /.":"->"|"//ArrayFlatten,"
",""])
```

Line 2 defines the helper operator `±`, which is used to make line 4 evaluate to:

```
{"_"  -> Array[If[#1 == n,          "_", " "] &, {n, n}], 
 "|"  -> Array[If[#2 == n,          "|", " "] &, {n, n}], 
 ":"  -> Array[If[#2 == 1,          ":", " "] &, {n, n}], 
 "\\" -> Array[If[#1 == #2,         "\\"," "] &, {n, n}], 
 "/"  -> Array[If[1 + n - #1 == #2, "/", " "] &, {n, n}], 
 " "  -> Array[If[0 == 1,           " ", " "] &, {n, n}]}
```

In line 3, the `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) takes a matrix representing the star of size 1 as well as the list of rules above. For the final steps, we use `ArrayFlatten`, which is shorter than `SubstitutionSystem`, and `StringRiffle`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 295 bytes

Solution is method `f`.

```java
String s(String s,int n){while(n-->0)s=" "+s;return s;}String f(int x){String n="\n",s="/",b="\\",o="",u="_";int i=0;for(x--;i<x;u+="_")o+=s(s,2*x-i+1)+s(b,2*i++)+n;o+=u+s+s(b,2*i)+u+n;while(i>=0)o+=s(b,x-i)+s(s,4*x-2*(x+~i--))+n;while(i++<x)o+=s("|",x)+s(s,x-i)+s(b,2*i)+s("|",x-i)+n;return o;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##RVDdbsIgGL2uT0G4AgGnZrtCfINdeTmXpdXqcAqmgLJ03at3Hy1mCcnH@c5P4JzKWynstTan/Vd/DdVZ79DuXDqHXkttUNtvfKPNETnyuHBtPDK0vX/qc02MEOs5dQojzJxsah8ag5zssvpAkjrSNmOj8NZgDvonzCsAW8ytwpgHhT@wTGKt5vJgGxKFkHoVZWCJopYpRxxfTqPQbEGZIxUAzRhlRgIZmHvsKAuwG9@n12o@eisOzuRz/BlCllMS2a8WgtJ/MWOrOKrxD@ZxVGdbjs5U2pnHf63s@iKX53zpYdys3qMLVJh7e3tHZXN0FLWTohiqTSRSyNT3oWpCJTDwcTRUlqiFhLFCL2kwgKO52Hw7X19mNvjZFaI9SUmzAzF0iOgmcLr@Dw) (JDK 8)

### Ungolfed

```java
String s(String s, int n) {
    while (n-- > 0)
        s = " " + s;
    return s;
}

String f(int x) {
    String
        n = "\n",
        s = "/",
        b = "\\",
        o = "",
        u = "_"
    ;
    int i = 0;
    for (x--; i < x; u += "_")
        o += s(s, 2*x - i + 1) + s(b, 2 * i++) + n;
    o += u + s + s(b, 2 * i) + u + n;
    while (i >= 0)
        o += s(b, x - i) + s(s, 4*x - 2*(x + ~i--)) + n;
    while (i++ < x)
        o += s("|", x) + s(s, x - i) + s(b, 2 * i) + s("|", x - i) + n;
    return o;
}
```

### Acknowledgments

- -1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: You can save a byte by lowering `x` by 1 right from the start: [`<T>String s(T s,int n){return"".format("%"+-~n+"s",s);}String f(int x){String n="\n",s="/",b="\\",o="",u="_";int i=0;for(x--;i<x;u+="_")o+=s(s,2*x-i+1)+s(b,2*i++)+n;o+=u+s+s(b,2*i++)+u+n;for(;i-->0;)o+=s(b,x-i)+s(s,4*x-2*(x+~i))+n;for(;++i<=x;)o+=s("|",x)+s(s,x-i)+s(b,2*i)+s("|",x-i)+n;return o;}`](https://tinyurl.com/yd5ym52v)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 137 bytes

```python
n=input()
b,f,s,v='\/ |'
for i in range(3*n):u=i/~-n*n*'_';d=f+i%n*2*s+b;print[u+d+u,b+s*2*(3*n+~i)+f,v+d.center(2*n)+v][i/n].center(4*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxNCsIwEEDhfU@RjaTJRAtRN5acpBaxJtHZTEN@CoL06rEu3H7wXnjn10y6VjJIoeRWNJPyKqnF8GvHPrzxc2TIkFi809O1R0niUgx2654kSX7jvTUecEdSywRTHyJSHgpYKGqCtOmvgRUFeLWAPTwcZRdbvY1gGQfsaPzbabNaz/UL)